# formally comparing model fit indices from two correlation matrices

Tags: r, meta-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I have a model that I would like to validate. I do not have raw data but am working only through correlation matrices.

Is there a way to compare model performance and fit in a statistically formal manner outside of only looking at fit indices?